# Is there anything like Eclipse Perspective in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, perspectives

I was wondering if there's anything like Eclipse Perspectives in Visual Studio (2008 or 2010).

For those unfamiliar with Eclipse, here's a [definition of Perspectives](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html):

> A perspective is a visual container
>   for a set of views and editors
>   (parts).  These parts exist wholly
>   within the perspective and are not
>   shared.  A perspective is also like a
>   page within a book.  It exists within
>   a window along with any number of
>   other perspectives and, like a page
>   within a book, only one perspective is
>   visible at any time.

Let me give you a visual example:

**Java Perspective:**
[image: Java Perspective]

**SVN Repository Perspective:**
[image: SVN Repository Perspective]

Maybe there is nothing like that straight out of the box, but with some plugin. If that's the case, it'll also be a valid answer.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Brian's blog post as a starting point and made a VS2010 extension: http://perspectives.codeplex.com/

More info here: http://csharpening.net/blog/?p=292

It's probably not as complete as the VSWindowManager but lets you save your configurations and create new ones. Let me know if it works out!

Answer (score 1):

I found this http://vswindowmanager.codeplex.com/ but it's for 2005.. there is a branch for 2008 in the source code but i don't know if it works... I think I'll give it a try and post any results...

It would be great if it works also for 2010!!! When you work in 1024*768 it's really annoying to rezise the windows every two seconds!!!

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my blog post which provides the ability to list and switch window layouts in Vs2008 and Vs2010: http://www.brianschmitt.com/2010/09/save-and-change-tool-layout-in-visual.html