# Visual Studio 2010 Different Projects Different Views

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way within Visual Studio 2010 to have different windows and panes viewed with different project types?  In other words, if you are doing a Windows Application certain panes are automatically open, but an ASP.NET project different panes are open, or a Database Project another set of panes are automatically opened.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. There is a way to export a layout as a subset of your preferences and settings and then re-import that once VS is open, but I'm guessing that would be time-consuming and probably get old after a few days.

I believe VS does support the notion of layouts or views, since it does switch between them when you go from development mode to debug, for example. So you'd have to figure out how that works and maybe automate it with a macro. I looked for some add-in or plugin that could do this and didn't really find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [visual studio perspectives extension](http://perspectives.codeplex.com/) that can do this:

Also, checkout this question:
[Is there anything like Eclipse Perspective in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347452/is-there-anything-like-eclipse-perspective-in-visual-studio)